# How to autocomplete only city(city-town-village)

Tags: here-api

Request 'https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?app_code=[app_code]&app_id=[app_id]&at=0,0&q=budapesht' return the list of different places, but I need only places with category city-town-village. How to filter only cities?

Answer (score 1):

If you use this query
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?at=47.4799441%2C18.9826451&q=town&result_types=category&app_id=[app_id]&app_code=[app_code]
you will only get back results of type "category" that start with "town".  That's not what is being asked for.

You can set "result_types=address" so that you don't get back chain, category, or place results, but currently there's no way of filtering such that you only get city-town-village.  You will also get administrative areas, streets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please try use parameter result_types=category and q="townhalls" or "government-community-facility" in autocomplete suggestions API.
And the category "city-town-village" seems no longer valid.

https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?at=47.4799441%2C18.9826451&q=town&result_types=category&app_id=[app_id]&app_code=[app_code]